# Batch-reading mesh3D objects with the 'file2mesh' function from the 'Morpho' package

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to batch-read a series of ply-meshes (as mesh3D objects), in order to slide semilandmarks with 'slider3d'. However, when I try to use a loop to read those files, I am told that the object 'Mesh' could not be found. This indicates that a mesh object must first be created in order to then be altered in a loop. How do I solve this?

Is there a simple function in the 'rgl' package that I overlooked?

Or is there an alternative to read all 3D-meshes in one folder, and  create a list that I can use to match files downstream?

```
library(Morpho)

FilesPLY <- list.files("HumerusPLY",pattern="*.ply")

for(j in 1:length(FilesPLY)){
Mesh[j] <- file2mesh(paste("HumerusPLY/",FilesPLY[j],sep=""), clean = TRUE, readcol = FALSE)
}
```

> Error: Object 'Mesh' could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is by creating a list of empty files, and then reading the meshes into the empty files. Oddly enough the first read-out results in an error, but it sets up the system for the read-in. I don't understand the problem behind it, but it works. Thus, here is the temporary solution:

```
library(Morpho)

# Read ply-list from subfolder "HumerusPLY/"; Create Mesh series of objects, and fill them
FilesPLY <- list.files("HumerusPLY/",pattern="*.ply")
for(i in 1:length(FilesPLY)) {
  assign(paste("Mesh",i,sep=""), i)
}
meshlist <- c(1:length(FilesPLY))
for (i in 1:length(meshlist)){
meshlist[i] <- paste("Mesh",meshlist[i],sep="")
}
meshlist <- noquote(meshlist)
ls()

##read ply-files; the second read fixes an error, but does not work without the first read
for(j in 1:length(meshlist)){
meshlist[j] <- file2mesh(paste("HumerusPLY/",FilesPLY[j],sep=""), clean = TRUE, readcol = FALSE)
}
for(j in 1:length(meshlist)){
meshlist[[j]] <- file2mesh(paste("HumerusPLY/",FilesPLY[j],sep=""), clean = TRUE, readcol = FALSE)
}
```